# How do I modify the `params` that were set in the controller in an action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I have the following parameters being passed to my `ProfilesController#Update`:

```
> profile_params[:videos_attributes]
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"1479585381276"=><ActionController::Parameters {"vimeo_url"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj2gkjh3-k", "official"=>"false", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: true>, "1479585385202"=><ActionController::Parameters {"vimeo_url"=>"https://vimeo.com/some-awesome-video", "official"=>"true", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

What I want to do is delete the hash with key `1479585381276` (or any hash for that matter)

I tried using `.delete(key)` and that doesn't seem to work.

```
> item
=> "1479585381276"
> profile_params[:videos_attributes].delete(item)
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"vimeo_url"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qas34Pce-k", "official"=>"false", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: true>
> profile_params[:videos_attributes]
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"1479585381276"=><ActionController::Parameters {"vimeo_url"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qas34Pce-k", "official"=>"false", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: true>, "1479585385202"=><ActionController::Parameters {"vimeo_url"=>"https://vimeo.com/some-awesome-video", "official"=>"true", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

The reason I want to do this is because when I evaluate the parameters, it still gets passed to the `@profile.update(profile_params)` in the latter half of my `Profiles#Update` and creates a record I don't want it to create.

So all I want to do is upon successful processing, delete it/pop it/remove it from the `profile_params[:videos_attributes]` hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`profile_params` returns you a new hash each time (with copy of whitelisted data from `params`). Modify `params` directly.

```
params[:profile][:videos_attributes].delete(item)
```

I've been burnt by this before. :)

Comment: This is 100% on the money. Thanks much meng!